# Colored trominoes touching corner-to-corner on a grid

Tags: logical-deduction

Let's have an 8x8 GRID to be filled with L-trominoes of 3 different colors. 64 squares leave room for 21 trominoes, so there should be 7 trominoes of each color and one empty square. Trominoes of the same color are not allowed to touch side-to-side anywhere.
In the presented example, there is an empty square in the position B3; trominoes of the same color touch corner-to-corner in two places marked with red. With the empty square in the B2 position (that is, one row higher), can you fill the grid with L-trominoes, such that trominoes of the same color touch corner-to-corner in only 2 places? [image: 8x8GRIDwith trominoes]

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Bubbler-4/svg-stuff-and-tools/raw/a042caf1a8a2d65cce93ee7d8e60d5d9641f7d3b/images/PuzzlingSE/Misc/Q112812.svg) satisfy "trominoes of the same color touch corner-to-corner in only 2 places"? Corner-to-corner touch occurs three times but at two places. (This is not an answer because it has 8 grays and 6 blues)

Comment: The question is specific...only two places is it allowed for trominoes to touch corner-to-corner. In your example you have thee places where trominoes meet corner-to-corner and the number of each color tromino is not equal.

Answer (score 4):

> Yes, there is a solution that involves 2 corner color shares. In this instance, blue and yellow. [image: solution]

Comment: But are rectangular 3x1 or 1x3 trominoes allowed?

Comment: I woule have to assume so. The question just asks for trominoes, no specifics on which type.

Comment: All trominoes are as shown in the example..

Comment: You could have clarified that better.